# How to display only specific data from a database Table in .NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to learn .NET MVC and I just met a little problem. I have a table in my database named **Cars**  that contains information about them(like location, Car ID ...) and I want to display on a page only the cars in a *given location* (specific rows).

I've tried it by adding the specific rows from the table to a list and pass it to the View but I don't understand how to read the details(Location...) and pass it to the controller to select those rows and add it to the list.
And how should be correct to bind the 2 Views, the one that gets the details and the one that displays the rows from the list?

Here's what I have tried:

Controllers:

```
 public ActionResult AvailableCars()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AvailableCars(string Location)
        {
            List<Cars> carList = null;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

             //add cars to the list
            }
            if(carList == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "No available cars");
            }

            return View(carList);
        }
```

Model:

```
 public partial class Cars
    {
        public int CarID { get; set; }
        public string Plate { get; set; }
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
    }
```

Views:

This one is for getting the details and it's working.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

This one is for displaying the rows from the list

```
@model IEnumerable<RentC.UI.Models.Cars>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Available Cars List";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Plate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Manufacturer)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Model)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Plate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Manufacturer)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CarID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.CarID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.CarID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

P.S. I've implemented the list adding part, but if I run the code, it says that the list is not initialized. That means that my data from the first View is not passed to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
 List<Cars> carList = null;
```

To:

```
 List<Cars> carList = new List<Cars>();
```

You must initialize the list before you can put things into it.